# How to set NSDateFormatter as per UIDatePicker language

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

My Date picker language is Francais, but when I am going to set that date to any of my UILabel then it is always set in English.

I am using this format `EEEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm`.

Anybuddy please help me to set date in Francais as per picker language.

Also you can refer image, so you can get clear my question even better.

[image: Date picker and set date label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set  date formatter to your language french

```
 dateFormatter.locale=[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:"fr"];
```

Comment: Thanks shtefane.. u saved my efforts and time.